# When use EF stored procedure to handle with breezejs, how to return error from SP to client side?

Tags: breeze

I call a raiserror in the SP, expect it will be returned to client side in some way, just like when I add raiserror to a trigger on a table, but now I don't see the message returned

"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the exception in either a breeze *EntityErrorsException* or a standard .NET *HttpResponseException*. The EntityErrorsException will allow you to pass additional information about exactly which entities are causing the error(s), if you have this information available on the server.

The discussion here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/server-side-validation discusses the EntityErrorsException in more detail.